# How do you force the scaling on a highchart axis to be recalculated

Tags: highcharts

I am using series.setVisible( ) in highcharts to show and hide the selected series.  When this happens there are times when the axis does not get rescaled.  Is there a way to tell the chart to force a rescaling of the axis based on the series in the chart.  I have tried the chart.redraw api but this does not do it.